# LibreOffice for Windows Security

Tags: windows, libreoffice

I use Windows and would like to install LibreOffice. Is there a "security team" checking the code for malware? In Linux I think it's done by the security team of the linux distribution. Who is doing this for the Windows version? Is it safe to use and install it or is there any chance of "easter egg" in the software?

Answer (score 1):

If you are concerned about LibreOffice, you should download from official sites.

https://www.libreoffice.org/download/

Please do not download from third-party sites.

Reference:

http://www.pcworld.com/article/2092480/filezilla-warns-of-large-malware-campaign.html

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I am actually concerned about the malware in the official code - I mean if there is any chance a contributer is including it in the software? Or is there a security team which checks the code before the release of the actual version?

Comment: It certainly is possible that Libreoffice (or any other code) gets contaminated at the source, but important packages have procedures in place to avoid that. They at least publish digital signatures to check. For more details, you'd have to contact them directly.